# Manipulate SVG in HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm having an problem with construction of a svg element using javascript in an html-embedded svg image. I created two files that should be exactly the same but one of them is being constructed with js.

**SVG.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Pozadí</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg
    id="pozadi"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    height="200"
    width="200"
   >
   <path
     d="M 0,0 L 150,150 L 100,150 L 150,150 L 150,100"
     style="stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px; stroke-linecap: round; fill: none;"
    >
    <animate
      from="M 0,0 L 150,0 L 115,35 L 150,0 L 115,-35"
      to="M 0,0 L 150,150 L 100,150 L 150,150 L 150,100"
      dur="10s"
      begin="5s"
      attributeType="XML"
      attributeName="d"
     >
    </animate>
   </path>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

**JS.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Pozadí</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg
    id="pozadi"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    height="200"
    width="200"
   >
  </svg>
  <script>
   var svg  = document.getElementById('pozadi');
   var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/','path'); //I have tried createElement(string) too
   path.setAttribute('style',"stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px; stroke-linecap: round; fill: none;");
   path.setAttribute('d',"M 0,0 L 150,150 L 100,150 L 150,150 L 150,100");
   var anim = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/','animate');
   anim.setAttribute('from','M 0,0 L 150,0 L 115,35 L 150,0 L 115,-35');
   anim.setAttribute('to','M 0,0 L 150,150 L 100,150 L 150,150 L 150,100');
   anim.setAttribute('dur','10s');
   anim.setAttribute('begin','5s');
   anim.setAttribute('attributeType','XML');
   anim.setAttribute('attributeName','d');
   path.appendChild(anim);
   svg .appendChild(path);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The second file, JS.html, is just white and plain.
I'm asking, how to correct it? Thanks, m93a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/','path');
```

is wrong. You want

```
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
```

Note the lack of a trailing / character. Same problem with

```
var anim = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/','animate');
```

If you fix these two lines you should see the arrow (I do in Firefox), here's a [jsfiddle to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/TuYYh/).

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you may have is that you run the script as soon as you load page, instead of waiting for all the elements to load.

So basically document.getElementById('pozadi'); might be null when you run it, and since you have an external request (http://www.w3.org/2000/svg) there is a good chance that happens.

Try adding an onload listener calling a function with your current script. If you have jQuery this is what you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/ready/. If not... make it manually.

Comment: document.getElementById('pozadi') does not depend on layout so you can run it any time. You don't need to use onload here.

Comment: Omg... since when? Put script on top and see the difference.

Comment: If the svg is "above" the script element, svg's dom should be ready to be used. If it is below, nothing but waiting can be done.

Comment: Since forever. getBBox does depend on layout for instance so you can't call that before onload but there's nothing in this case that does.

Comment: Whatever... encourage bad practices, that's the way to do it.