# Embed SVG in HTML with some event-based behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG file that I would like to embed on a website (a WordPress blog, so hopefully something that Wordpress allows). But I want the SVG to react to the user. Specifically, there is some text that I want to hide unless the user zooms in.
Ideally, the SVG would be inside some viewport so that the user events are caught inside that viewport and not in the entire website. That is, the user zooms in on the viewport (by pressing a button that is on the viewport, maybe) but the website remains the same. This is not a strict requirement, I could just put it on the website and use the Ctrl+'+' and Ctrl+'-' events on the page.

Is there any JS library that allows doing this easily?
I could potentially add stuff to the XML of the SVG if needed.

Note that I am not willing to rebuild the SVG from JS, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903425/manipulate-svg-in-html-with-js), I want to load it. I can add JS code in the SVG, beforehand.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I'm aware there isn't a cross-browser standard API for zooming (that's more of an individual function in each browser). It seems a little anti-UX to require this as part of the interaction, especially if people use zoom levels for visual impairments. Are you sure you don't want to simulate a "zoom in" effect instead by animating surrounding elements?

Comment: Thanks. The SVG is quite big and has a lot of small elements, so it's impractical for me to move things around. People with visual impairments is why I thought of the viewport thing. It would look like when there is a PDF embedded inside a website and then it has some buttons to only zoom the PDF. I would like something similar for SVG.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more detailed or include some visual examples, I can't see why you wouldn't scale an SVG to simulate zooming rather than using browser zoom, and I'm still not sure you want to be simulating an accessibility feature by repurposing a real accessibility feature. Surely a false viewport with false zooming would just be removing and rebuilding browser behaviour?

Comment: Can you link any examples of the sort of thing you're after? Maybe there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: I want pretty much this: https://pdfobject.com/ but for SVG files. And with the addition that some SVG elements will be hidden until you press the "+" button. Thanks again

Comment: That example does not use the browser's built-in zoom. Although the browser zoom can be used, it scales it differently (and some parts incorrectly). I'm also still not too clear on how a PDF rendering engine would have an SVG equivalent. This still looks like something you would need to simulate (by scaling your own application/elements) rather than hooking into browser functionality.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I don't need to use the browser zoom events, I suggested it thinking it may be simpler. But I am happy not to use them and have two buttons like in the PDF example. I do not see why it's not clear that there could be a SVG rendering engine: web browsers open SVG files and display them nicely (they support SVG 1.1 at least). I'm just asking to embed an SVG inside some "viewport" that has two buttons to zoom in and out. You can open a SVG in Chrome and zoom in and out with Ctrl++, I want that, but embedded in a website.

Comment: I understand that, but my point is that there isn't really any embedding or viewport involved, you just want it to look like there is. An SVG, unlike a PDF, is natively supported, so what you would do is create a background or box, and scale the svg inside it (using a couple of buttons you can create). It's similar to how elements are often used to simulate a checkbox (so that it can be styled, unlike the native one), with click events being passed to the real (hidden) checkbox with JavaScript.

Comment: For example, if you placed your SVG inside a div with "overflow:hidden" set, and then scaled or animated it with the Snap.svg library (according to zoom buttons or whatever else), anything that fell outside the container div would be hidden, so it would look like a viewport of sorts. You could also track the current zoom level that you set (using a variable you define), and adjust/animate your SVG accordingly.

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom, part of the [tag:d3.js] library. Most of the linked examples construct the SVGs from data, but you could just as easily reference preexisting elements and manipulate them.